# enum in a namespace

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, c++11

Is there a point of doing somthing like this:

```
namespace status{
  enum status{
    ok,
    error
  };
}
```

and use it like that `status::ok`

Or should i do this:

```
enum status{
  status_ok,
  status_error
};
```

and use it like this `status_ok`?

**Update:** 
With C++11 you now should do this:

```
enum class status {
    ok,
    error
};
```

and use like this: `status::ok`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I personally don't like the second variation because the `status_` part seems redundant to me. The former version avoids that problem, but having a type `status::status` looks strange too. Furthermore, a namespace is open to modification, so in case somebody did something like

```
namespace status {
  void error( const char *msg );
}
```

You would get a compiler error since the function `error` clashes with your `enum` value.

I prefer to use a third variation:

```
struct MouseButton {
  enum Value {
    Left, Middle, Right
  };
};
```

This lets me write functions like

```
void handleMouseButton( MouseButton::Value b ) {
  switch ( b ) {
    case MouseButton::Left:   // ...
    case MouseButton::Middle: // ...
    case MouseButton::Right:  // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

What you want has just been added to C++ when enabling C++0x extensions. However, if you cannot use C++0x features, I suggest to do this:

```
struct status
{
    enum value
    {
        ok,
        error
    };
};
```

With a such declaration you can write:

```
status::value var = status::ok;
```

Such a structure will also allow you to declare functions related to the status type inside the `struct` scope. For example, the status `struct` could contain methods to convert to/from a string.

Comment: Plus, this solution allow you to nest you enumeration declaration inside classes or structures, which is not possible using namespaces.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not worried about using `enum status` type as such, then you can keep it anonymous.

```
namespace status{
  enum {  // <--- no name
    ok,
    error
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the namespace approach, as it allows `using namespace` and using the shorter enum values if only one enum is used in a piece of code.

It's mostly a matter of personal preference, however, I feel that solving (potential) name clashes in C++ is best done using namespaces, as that's the point of having namespaces in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should access `enum`s using the scope operator, `::` not the dot `.` operator; i.e. `status::ok`

Both are fine it's what you feel would be more readable. Note you can also use (without the `namespace`)

```
enum status{
   ok,
   error
}
```

and still use `status::ok` but some compilers will warn you that the extra `status::` is unnecessary.

EDIT: Accessing an `enum` using `::` seems to work only with MS visual-c++

Comment: No, it is an error. Compilers say that `status` must be either a namespace or a class/struct.

Comment: I tested it with g++, icc, icpc and indeed it throws an error. With MS VS2010 however it compiles fine. And there I was thinking I was writing nice portable code ;)

Comment: In C++03 it's a non-standard MSVC extension, but in C++11 it's standard.