# Resolve enum naming issue - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, enums, compiler-errors

I'm trying to include QSoundeffect in my project, however I get a compiler error 
`/home/innereye/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtMultimedia/qsoundeffect.h:76: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token`

When I look at the relevant line in code, I see an enum with the name Status declared.

```
enum Status
{
        Null,
        Loading,
        Ready,
        Error
};
```

If I change the enums name to Status1, compilation is Ok, but I wan't to avoid it and not change the Qt source code. 
Is there a way to see why the compiler cant resolve it? I don't have any enum in my project with that name, but maybe one of the libraries or external sources use it?

Using Qt 5.7 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Use a namespace for *your* types. Good rule of thumb in general. And particularly useful when dealing with libraries that haven't caught on to the notion of good namespace partitioning, like Qt.

Comment: Do you have some defines in your code?

Comment: I have defines, but none of them is called Status. My project does not contain the word 'Status' as a name

Comment: have namespace to your enum. Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090130/enum-in-a-namespace

Comment: As I stated, I don't wan't to change the code in the Qt source. Is there a way to find out why the compiler produces the error?

Comment: @StoryTeller naming my types won't help, I don't think that my types are the ones that are causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, after some trial and error I figured out exactly what is wrong, and moving the #include line before include GL/glx.h solved the problem. It was due to the fact that  /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h has the following line - `#define Status int`